# Gradle Build Android Project "Could not resolve all dependencies" error

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I'm trying to build my first project with Gradle and I think my gradle files and settings are correct.

I'm using only one module and Support V4 + AppCompatBar libraries.

**Project - build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**Project - settings.gradle**

```
include ':AssignmentTempos21'
```

**Main module - build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

**Console output with -i flag:**

```
MacBook-Air-de-Cesar-2:AssignmentTempos21 menor$ ./gradlew -i clean assemble
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/menor/workspace_android/AssignmentTempos21/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/menor/workspace_android/AssignmentTempos21/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'AssignmentTempos21', project ':AssignmentTempos21']
Evaluating root project 'AssignmentTempos21' using build file '/Users/menor/workspace_android/AssignmentTempos21/build.gradle'.
Compiling build file '/Users/menor/workspace_android/AssignmentTempos21/build.gradle' using BuildScriptClasspathScriptTransformer.
Compiling build file '/Users/menor/workspace_android/AssignmentTempos21/build.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
Evaluating project ':AssignmentTempos21' using build file '/Users/menor/workspace_android/AssignmentTempos21/AssignmentTempos21/build.gradle'.
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':AssignmentTempos21'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':AssignmentTempos21:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+.
        Required by:
            AssignmentTempos21:AssignmentTempos21:unspecified
      > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+.
        Required by:
            AssignmentTempos21:AssignmentTempos21:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 40.787 secs
```

Comment: Please go to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347) and star it.

It seems there are a lot of problems because there were a lot of libraries unpublished from jCenter.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As Peter says, they won't be in Maven Central

from the Android SDK Manager download the 'Android Support Repository' and a Maven repo of the support libraries will be downloaded to your Android SDK directory (see 'extras' folder)

to deploy the libraries to your local .m2 repository you can use [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer)

**2017 edit:**

you can now reference the Google online M2 repo

```
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Downloading the "Android Support Repository" from "Android SDK Manager" definitively solve this issue I got in Android Studio 0.4.3 projects. It remains only a little pity about a deprecation message by Gradle but this is another story so i open [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496956/gradle-deprecation-relying-on-packaging-to-define-the-extension-of-the-main-art)

Comment: could you please explain step by step: I mean first download `maven-android-sdk-deployer` , second what?

Comment: @H.Aqjn I've rearranged the answer to read a little better (I think), if you're using Gradle you should be fine just to download the support repository from the SDK Manager

Answer (score 50):

Go to wherever you installed Android Studio (for me it's under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\`) and open `sdk\tools`, then run `android.bat`. From here, update and download any missing build-tools and make sure you update the Android Support Repository and Android Support Library under Extras. Restart Android Studio after the SDK Manager finishes.

It seems that Android Studio completely ignores any installed Android SDK files and keeps a copy of its own. After running an update, everything compiled successfully for me using compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+`

Comment: This really helped me I expected Android Studio to be using the Android SDK that I had manually installed on my machine. Having the IDE use its own Android SDK instead of using one defined by the developer is really annoying. The SDK should be separate to the IDE.

Comment: I had NO IDEA that Android Studio had its own version of the SDK under AppData. This is super confusing!

Comment: I had to install Extras/Android Support Library, restart SDK Manager and then Android Support Repository appeared.

Comment: This got rid of an error about "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+" for me.

Comment: Well, I also had similar confusion, when I noticed multiple Android SDK instances on my Ubuntu machine. Hence I had a bad suspicion, that AndroidStudio creates its own instance. Currently I run AS v.2.1.2 and this same issue is still present. I wonder if the team plans to fix it some day soon, or they consider it a feature :)

Answer (score 27):

If you are running on headless CI and are installing the Android SDK through command line, make sure to include the m2repository packages in the `--filter` argument:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter platform-tools,build-tools-19.0.1,android-19,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository
```

**Update**

As of Android SDK Manager rev. 22.6.4 this does not work anymore. Try this instead:

```
android list sdk --all
```

You will get a list of all available SDK packages. Look up the numerical values of the components from the first command above ("Google Repository" and others you might be missing).

Install the packages using their numerical values:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter <num>
```

**Update #2 (Sept 2017)**

With the "new" Android SDK tools that were released earlier this year, the `android` command is now deprecated, and similar functionality has been moved to a new tool called `sdkmanager`:

List installed components:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

Update installed components:

```
sdkmanager --update
```

Install a new component (e.g. build tools version `26.0.0`):

```
sdkmanager 'build-tools;26.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice command line! Unfortunately, now (Android SDK Manager rev. 22.6.4 (from About in GUI)) the response I get to it is: `Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'`, also for `'android-19'` and `'extra-android-support'`. Cheers!

Comment: I´m getting "SWT folder '/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/arm' does not exist

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I've run: `android list sdk --all |grep -i repos`, it gives me `"98-Android Support Repository, revision 6"` and `"106-Google Repository, revision 11"`. Then I've installed both packages running `android update sdk -u -a -t 98,106` which finally solved the problem (I'm using adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip, don't know which SDK Manager version it is).

Comment: You saved many lives here by mentioning the need of installing Google Repository. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah mine was also due to missing -- 
142- Android Support Repository, revision 21
150- Google Repository, revision 22

Comment: The --all command did the trick for me (google play services not building in headless environment): android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter 147,148,154,155

Answer (score 5):

These dependencies don't exist in Maven Central ([see this](http://search.maven.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

```
compileSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 17
```

change the compile version from 18 to 17

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:17.0.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:17.0.+"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kassim's answer:

> As Peter says, they won't be in Maven Central
>
> Either use [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to deploy the libraries to your
>   local repository
>
> Or from Android SDK Manager download the Android Support Repository
>   (in Extras) and an M2 repo of the support libraries will be downloaded
>   to your Android SDK directory

I also had to update the "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries" in Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

to echo @friederbluemle, you can also just launch the SDK manager from the command line if you have the Android SDK tools installed:

`$ android`

and then in the UI that pops up, select the tools/repositories that need to be installed -- in your case the support library repo

Answer (score 1):

**Try to turn off your firewall**, **`it works for me`**. It seems that android studio wants to download some dependencies and our firewall prevents it from downloading it, **`just be aware that turning your firewall off may lower the security of your computer`**. If you have more time you can manually allow your android studio to bypass your firewall, this way you can turn on your firewall while allowing android studio to download anything that it wants.

Answer (score 1):

I had this message in Android Studio 2.1.1 in the Gradle Build tab. I installed a lot of files from the SDK Manager but it did not help.

I needed to click the next tab "Gradle Sync". There was a link "Install Repository and sync project" which installed the "Android Support Repository".

Answer (score 1):

1. Install android sdk manager
2. check if building tools installed. install api 23.
3. from the Android SDK Manager download the 'Android Support Repository'
4. remove cordova-plugin-android-support-v4
5. build

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```