# Error build Android in Cordova: Unspecified required by?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to build my app in Cordova 5.4 using `cordova run android`. I'm getting this:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
```

I can't seem to track this one down. Look familiar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045712/gradle-build-android-project-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-error-but-i-t

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if this should be a comment but I don't have enough points yet to do so.

Please try  to install `Android Support Repository` in the `Android SDK Manager`.

Then check whether this works

```
cordova build android --verbose
```

If it's successful,

```
cordova run android --verbose
```

Source:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

Check for `android-support-v4.jar` in your project build path.