# How to resolve "Gradle 'My First Project' project refresh failed Error:Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to resolve this error while creating new project in the android studio.

```
Gradle 'My First Project' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.aar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.aar'.
Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.19.14] failed: Connection timed out: connect
Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: Can you add your gradle file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Build Android Project "Could not resolve all dependencies" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045712/gradle-build-android-project-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-error)

Comment: Looks like google repository is missing. And please add both the gradle files.